# How to return true if name and password both match? (MySQL/C#)

Tags: c#, mysql

I am currently working on a simple login system with C# and MySQL and I have everything working so far but I can't seem to get the login verification working, I can't work out the correct way of checking the records in the table as I have tried a few different ways that I found online but none were working.

```
public bool loginCorrect(String name, String password)
    {
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true) {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand ("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE name = @UserName AND password = @Password")) {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@UserName", name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@Password", password);
                //Now we are going to read the data imput
                MySqlDataReader myLoginReader = cmd.ExecuteReader ();
                //if the data matches the rows (username, password), then you enter to the page                 
                bool isExist = myLoginReader.HasRows();

                //Close Reader                 
                myLoginReader.Close ();            
            }                          
            //Close Connection             
            this.CloseConnection ();
        }

        return isExist;
    }
```

This is the current code for the login verification which doesn't work. I want the boolean to return true when the passed parameters name and password match which the ones in the database table 'logins'.

Below is my working Insert method just in case you need to compare the structure.

```
public void Insert(String username, String password)
    {

        string query = "INSERT INTO logins (name, password) VALUES ('" + username + "','" + password + "')";

        //open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection () == true) 
        {
            //Create command and assign query
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

            //Execute command
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //close connection
            this.CloseConnection();

        }

    }
```

**EDIT:**
I have altered the loginCorrect method as suggested and I get these errors when compiling:
bool isExist = myLoginReader.HasRows(); // Non-Invocable member 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.HasRows' cannot be used like a method.

And:
return isExist; // The name 'isExist' does not exist in the current context.

**EDIT 2**
Current Code

```
        public void Insert(String name, String password)
    {

        //open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection()) 
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO logins (name, password) VALUES (@UserName, @Password)";

            //Create command and assign query
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

            //Add parameters
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@UserName", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@Password", password);

            //Execute command
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //close connection
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }

    public bool loginCorrect(String name, String password)
    {
        bool isExist = false;
        if (this.OpenConnection()) {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand ("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE `name` = @UserName AND password = @Password")) {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@UserName", name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@Password", password);
                //Now we are going to read the data imput
                MySqlDataReader myLoginReader = cmd.ExecuteReader ();
                //if the data matches the rows (username, password), then you enter to the page                 
                isExist = myLoginReader.HasRows;

                //Close Reader                 
                myLoginReader.Close ();            
            }                          
            //Close Connection             
            this.CloseConnection ();
        }

        return isExist;
    }
```

Which gives

> System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open.

**SOLUTION**

```
        public void Insert(String name, String password)
    {

        //open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection()) 
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO logins (name, password) VALUES (@UserName, @Password)";

            //Create command and assign query
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

            //Add parameters
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@UserName", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@Password", password);

            //Execute command
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //close connection
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }

    public bool loginCorrect(String name, String password)
    {
        bool isExist = false;
        if (this.OpenConnection()) {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand ("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE `name` = @UserName AND password = @Password", connection)) {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@UserName", name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@Password", password);
                //Now we are going to read the data imput
                MySqlDataReader myLoginReader = cmd.ExecuteReader ();
                //if the data matches the rows (username, password), then you enter to the page                 
                isExist = myLoginReader.HasRows;

                //Close Reader                 
                myLoginReader.Close ();            
            }                          
            //Close Connection             
            this.CloseConnection ();
        }

        return isExist;
    }
```

The problem was not passing the connection in the loginCorrect method

Comment: Firstly, parametize your inserts to avoid SQL injection. Here's a video on the topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jKylhJtPmI

Comment: Even if you find a technical way of solving the problem, please scrap the code and [start from scratch](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1054022/335858).

Comment: @Steve I guess it doesn't really matter as he said the insert works. Do you believe `SqlDataReader` fails because of that?

Comment: For one, you will need to add `@` to your command parameter names   e,g, `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@UserName", name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@Password", password);`

Comment: By "not working" you mean doesn't compile, throws error, always returns false or what?

Comment: Also, seems like `SqlDataReader` has a more appropriate function `.HasRows()`

Comment: HasRows is a property, not a method, right?  You should lose the parenthesis.

Comment: Do not continually change your original question embedding the suggestion received. This makes comments and answer incoherent with your problem

Comment: @AgapwIesu correct, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, combined with some of the comments we gave you:

**User check:**

```
public bool loginCorrect(String name, String HASHED_AND_SALTED_PASSWORD)
    {
        bool isExist;
        if (this.OpenConnection()) {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE `name` = @UserName AND password = @Password")) {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@UserName", name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@Password", HASHED_AND_SALTED_PASSWORD);
                //Now we are going to read the data imput
                SqlDataReader myLoginReader = cmd.ExecuteReader ();
                //if the data matches the rows (username, password), then you enter to the page                 
                isExist = myLoginReader.HasRows;

                //Close Reader                 
                myLoginReader.Close ();            
            }                          
            //Close Connection             
            this.CloseConnection ();
        }

        return isExist;
    }
```

If you return inside the if, the connections won't be closed.

**Insert** - I'm not too experienced with C# classes, hope I did it correctly.

```
public void Insert(String username, String password)
{
    //Hash and salt password here (this is pseudo code)
    String HASHED_AND_SALTED_PASSWORD = StrongHash(password + GenerateSalt());

    //open connection
    if (this.OpenConnection()) 
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO logins (`name`, password) VALUES (@UserName, @Password)";

        //Create command and assign query
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

        //Add parameters
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@UserName", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@Password", HASHED_AND_SALTED_PASSWORD);

        //Execute command
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //close connection
        this.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

A few other things - **Make sure you store a properly hashed and salted password, using a strong hashing algorithm.** Even if this is for a school project, you'd want to get used to best practices.
I've fixed a few unnecessary things I saw like `if (this.OpenConnection() == true)`.

Let us know if this works.

EDIT:
Sorry, my bad. HasRows is a property, not a function. Try this instead: `myLoginReader.HasRows;` (Removed parentheses)
Also, declare `Bool isExist` at the top.

Comment: Using your suggestion, only two lines are now giving errors:
String HASHED_AND_SALTED_PASSWORD = StrongHash(password + GenerateSalt()); // StrongHash and GenerateSalt don't exist in current context

And:
return isExist; // isExist doesn't exist in current context

Comment: As I mentioned, `String HASHED_AND_SALTED_PASSWORD = StrongHash(password + GenerateSalt());` is pseudo code, it won't run.
I believe someone gave you a link in the comments to a guide explaining how to save passwords, until you follow it ignore my `HASHED_AND_SALTED_PASSWORD` variable and use the `password` variable you were using before.

Comment: Okay, I declared isExist and using my password variable I get this exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open.

Comment: Say, where is the `connection` variable in the insert coming from? I believe you need it in the user check as well. Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: They are both getting it from the same place when using if(this.OpenConnection()){}
Both Insert and User Check are in the same Class DataBase.cs along with OpenConnection

Comment: I'm a bit confused that you used `SqlCommand` for one check and `MySqlCommand` for the other. Is there a specific reason? Try using `MySqlCommand` for both (since you know it's working) and passing `connection` in the user check as well

Comment: I've been using MySqlCommand for both but I think I posted the wrong one, and how do you mean by passing connection?
**See Edit 2**

Comment: `MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);` instead of `MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);`

Comment: Yes! That solved the problem. Passing the connection meant that there were no errors and the correct result was returned (true). I will post the final solution